# Car animation in JS with 5 buttons to determine the state. Program runs through loop but doesn't perform all methods in Evaluate()

Tags: javascript, html, animation

This should show a car that starts driving when you press the start-button, stops when you press the stop-button, etc...

I made an evaluate method which determines what button triggered the event and then decides which action should be performed.
All the "action"-methods seem to work fine but there is a problem when I use a setTimeOut on the "Validate"-method. The console continuously logs "updating..." but the car's x-values don't go up unless you manually press the button every time.

How could I make this program perform either which method behind the buttons continuously while still having it responding to another button?

Thanks in advance!

```
<input type="button" value="start" id="start" onclick="Validate(this.id);">
```

The buttons look like this:

Here is the code:

```
<script>
        var c, ctx;
        c = document.getElementById('c');
        ctx = c.getContext('2d');
        var x, y, vx, l, b, s;
        x = 10;
        y = 380;
        l = 32;
        b = 130;
        s = 10;
        vx = 2;

        var car = new auto(x, y, l, b, s, vx);
        car.draw();

        var temp;
        var mission;

        function auto(x, y, l, b, s, vx) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.l = l;
            this.b = b;
            this.s = s;
            this.vx = vx;
            this.wx = this.x + (this.b * 0.25);
            this.wy = this.y + (this.l * 1.12);

            this.draw = function () {
                //car body
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.fillStyle = "#ff0000";
                ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.b, this.l);
                ctx.fillRect(this.x + (this.b * 0.3), this.y - this.l, this.b / 3, this.l);
                //wheels
                ctx.arc(this.wx, this.wy, this.s, 0, 180, false);
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(this.wx + (this.b/2), this.wy, this.s, 0, 180, false);
                ctx.closePath();
                ctx.stroke();
            };
        }

        function Validate(val) {
            mission=val;
            console.log(mission);
            ClearScreen(700);
            Update(mission);
            car.draw();
            setTimeout(Validate(val),1000);
        }

        function ClearScreen(square_size) {
            temp = ctx.save();
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, square_size, square_size);
        }

        function Update(val) {
            console.log("Updating...");
            switch (val) {
            case "start":
                Start(car);
                break;
            case "stop":
                Stop(car);
                break;
            case "reverse":
                Reverse(car);
                break;
            case "accelerate":
                Accelerate(car);
                break;
            case "restart":
                Reset(car);
                break;
            }
        }

        function Start() {
            car.x += car.vx;
            car.wx +=car.vx;
        }

        function Stop() { 
            car.x = car.x;
            car.wx = car.wx;
        }

        function Reverse() {
            car.x -= car.vx;
            car.wx -= car.vx;
        }

        function Accelerate() {
            car.vx *= 2;
        }

        function Reset() {
            car = new auto(x,y,l,b,s,vx);
        }


    </script>
```

Comment: Could you put a piece of code? It will be difficult to help you otherwise.

Comment: Not regarding the question, but: `Stop()` doesn't do anything. You could just as well not call Stop at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
setTimeout(Validate(val),1000);
```

Change your timeout to look like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    Validate(val)
},1000);
```

The way you wrote it, you were trying to run the result of Validate(val) after a second, not the function itself.

*(In other words: JavaScript was trying to immediately evaluate "Validate(val)" and run the result after the specified time instead of being pointed to the function which sould be run)*

Also as I pointed in the comments, you don't need the `Stop()` function. Also currently you have no way of stopping the loop. Everytime you click any button you add a new thread that will call the button's function.

You might want to learn about `setInterval` and `clearInterval` instead.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval